# Effect of hiding in polymorphism

Tags: java

I have difficulty understanding the following behaviour.

```
class A {    
    public String string = "a";    
    public String toString() {
        return string;
    }
}

class B extends A {   
}

public class Demo {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {   
        B b = new B();
        b.string = "c";
        System.out.println(b);    
    }  
}
```

The output of the program is 'c'. This is expexted behaviour. But if class B is changed as follows,

```
class B extends A { 
 public String string = "b";
}
```

Now the program prints 'a' instead of 'c'. Why the statement: b.string = "c"; is not taken into account? Thanks in advance..

Comment: I think I found the answer to my problem.. 

When we hide a variable in sub class, there will be 2 different variables (in 2 memory locations), one for super class and one for sub class. 

When we don't hide a variable in sub class, there is one and only one variable (in 1 memory location) shared by both super class and sub class. 

The method: toString() is not overridden in sub class B. So the version from super class A is executed.